# Basex Rest API rejects query while admin page allows it

Tags: basex

When I send a query xml doc like this

```
<query><text><![CDATA[
let $facts := fn:collection("factbook/factbook.xml")/mondial
let $c := ("Antarktika", "Atlantis")
for $name at $id in $c
return
insert node (<continent id="f0_aaa{$id}" name="{$name}" />) into $facts
]]></text></query>
```

to the REST API using

```
curl -i --data '...' 'http://localhost:8984/rest'
```

BaseX will report the following error:

```
[XPST0003] Incomplete FLWOR expression: expecting 'return'.
```

If I execute the same query on the web admin query page, the query is accepted and the nodes are inserted.

Why is the REST call rejected? Is there any further restriction that does not apply to the admin interface?

If I remove the `let`s and expand the corresponding variables, the query is accepted by REST API:

```
<query><text><![CDATA[
for $name at $id in ("Antarktika", "Atlantis")
return
insert node (<continent id="f0_aaa{$id}" name="{$name}" />) into fn:collection("factbook/factbook.xml")/mondial
]]></text></query>
```

The REST user has write permission. I'm using BaseX 9.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was not the query, but the `--data` option of `curl` in combination with `@` to send file content. This option strips linebreaks (CR and LF) before sending. With `--data-binary '@...'` the query works as expected.